# Google Analytics event tracking not working - due to Sitecore adding a variable?

Tags: google-analytics

We recently switched to Sitecore CMS, and I seem to be having a problem with Event tracking as a result.

Any file extension is being tracked successfully using GTM and Event tracking as long as the link is pure - ie fetched automatically using Sitecore assets.

However, if I link to a document in the media library using the text editor, it automatically adds `?la=en` to the end of the URL. (It used to have loads more code added, but our developer removed this.) I haven never been able to see these links as Events in GA, and I think it is because of this variable that gets added.

Has anyone come across this issue, and have any suggestions?

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: Can you post the triggers in GTM for these events? Could be that your triggers are too specific causing the ?la=en part to not register

Comment: Thanks @XTOTHEL As I understand triggers, they are simply file extensions such as .pdf or .xlsx, and I have a regex which lists all possible extensions.

Comment: Could it be the '$' at the end of my regex, saying don't track anything which has anything else after the normal extension?

Comment: This is my trigger:

Click url matches RegEx \.(docx|gif|mp(2|3|4|e?g)|pdf|png|pptx|wav|wma|wmv|xlsx|xml|xhtml|zip)$

Comment: Yes you got it. The regex indicates the url must END with an extension. You can try taking it off and see how much it changes your tracking or change it to accept the parameters pattern.

Comment: Early indicators are good! In real time I seem to be getting these download clicks as events now, which is great. Oddly the preview pane doesn't show the tag getting fired even if I open the document in a new window (ie the pdf doesn't replace my browser window with the preview pane) but the event seems to be taking place in Real Time GA now.

I'll see how this affects my live events over the next few days, but it looks good. Thanks @XTOTHEL!